# Simple C++ Substring Issue

Tags: c++, string, substring, substr

The program does not properly find the substrings of each section of the name "John Fitzgerald Kennedy", and cannot output each name on a separate line.  The program outputs a out of range exception and does not even show the second name, only the first.  How would I ouput each name on each separate line?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string fullName="",
        firstName="",
        middleName="",
        lastName="";

cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
cin>>fullName;

firstName=fullName.substr(0,4);
middleName=fullName.substr(4,14);
lastName=fullName.substr(14,19);

cout<<firstName<<endl;
cout<<middleName<<endl;
cout<<lastName;

cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin>>fullName;
```

stops reading the standard input when it encounters the first space. What you need is a command like

```
getline(cin, fullName);
```

to read the entire line along with the spaces and then chunk them to get different parts of the name.

Comment: That was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to note is that:

```
firstName=fullName.substr(0,4);
middleName=fullName.substr(4,14);
lastName=fullName.substr(14,19);
```

The second parameter in `substr` is the `length of the substring`, **NOT** the end index of the substring, if you do not mean that your first name is 4 characters long, middle name is 14 characters long, etc, you probably need to update them to the following:

```
firstName=fullName.substr(0,4);
middleName=fullName.substr(4,10);
lastName=fullName.substr(14,5);
```